# Terminal alternative to GNOME Keyring (Seahorse)

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, seahorse

I am currently using GNOME Keyring (codenamed `seahorse`). (*Edit*: newer versions of this application are now called "GNOME Passwords and Keys"). I am using it to manage my SSH passwords.

I would like to know if there are any command-line alternatives to this, which I can use in situations when I don't have access to the UI. I am currently running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: this probably is what you are looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18927/how-to-enter-the-default-keyring-password-via-the-command-line ?

Comment: This is not a duplicate: that question is about _interfacing_ with GNOME keyring. This question is about _finding an alternative_ to GNOME keyring.

Comment: As @AndreaCorbellini wrote, this is not a duplicate question.
I wanted to add https://github.com/jaraco/keyring/ as a possible answer, but I can't. And it's not appropriate for the the 'duplicate-origin' as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, `gnome-keyring` is not a GUI tool. Seahorse is. And `gnome-keyring` infrastructure can be accessed via command line, using [this project](https://launchpad.net/gkeyring).

This is using the Python bindings that Rinzwind mentions in his comment, and using this tool, you can simply do this:

```
./gkeyring.py get -s myserver.com -p ftp -u user
```

> This will look for all keyring items concerning server myserver.com
>   with protocol ftp and username user.

as mentioned in [this blog](http://kparal.wordpress.com/2009/09/29/command-line-access-to-gnome-keyring/).

Comment: Looks like this no longer works in Ubuntu 18.04 because the gnomekeyring module no longer exists for python.

Comment: look at https://pypi.org/project/keyring/

Comment: Unfortunately installing `gnome-keyring` installs 70MB+ including icons. Clunky on light servers

Comment: ... and to make matters worse, [gkeyring](https://github.com/kparal/gkeyring) is not maintained any longer. The package maintainer suggests using `secret-tool` and/or pypi.org/project/keyring instead.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use gnome key ring you can always use the kernal keyring...

See my notes...
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/crypto/passwd_caching.txt

And more specifically
https://antofthy.gitlab.io/info/crypto/keyring_linux_kernal.txt

Comment: Can it be used with subversion?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem with [gnome-keyring-cli](https://github.com/drafnel/gnome-keyring-cli).

To install it:

- clone repo
- be sure glib-devel and libgnome-keyring-devel (or your system equivalent) are available
- compile just invoking make
- by hand copy the gnome-keyring-cli binary at the destination of your choice (my is ~/bin/)

With gnome-keyring-cli you can lookup, add, remove, etc. It's not very user friendly but it's doing the job.