# trigger x-gnome-autostart after reboot over ssh

Tags: ssh, autostart

I have a desktop running Ubuntu 18.04 at my workplace, that I sometimes restart over `ssh`. I have some applications set to autostart, two of which sync files for me (nextcloud and insync). What I want to achieve is to have these apps also start when I restart the machine, so the file sync features also turn on. As far as I understand the ssh -X type of commands would allow me to run X through ssh, but would kill the processes I start when I terminate the ssh session. This is not what I am looking for. I want to start my desktop session preferable through the commandline, so when I go back to my workplace and actually sit in front of the machine, it just looks as if restarted the machine sitting in front of it.

Comment: Why not create services for the applications you want autostarted?  Define one time systemd services that run as you.  These services would then run whenever the system rebooted without you having to log in and run them from the command line.

Comment: Would this work for applications that do not have a headless mode and need X to start?

Comment: Why do you need X to start if you are just syncing files?

Comment: Because the desktop client is GUI, and is already set up to sync in a specific way, while there isn't a headless client to do that. I don't want to reinvent the wheel so, the easiest for me would be if the normal GUI session could be started and my user logged in somehow, which would also be a generic solution for similar issues (i.e. it could also restart torrent client etc.).

Comment: If you require a GUI for the backups, then what I am suggesting will not work.  Services tend to run as background processes.  Any output they generate usually goes to some kind of log file.

Comment: Do I have this straight? You want to reboot your system remotely and have it automatically log into your account? Are you concerned about the security implications? While I've never done this, I've done something like this, and I think it would work for remote connections as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to remotely log into your account after reboot. You should probably only do this if your system is in a secure location. At any rate, I'll tell you how this could be accomplished.

*Note: These will not work with FDE because you would also have to decrypt your system at boot time.*

### Option 1: Just configure your system to automatically login to your account

This bypasses the login screen and simply logs you into your computer. To do this, open the system settings and navigate to **Details -> Users**. Click the **Unlock** button in the top right. Select your user, and enable **Automatic Login**.

*EDIT: Unlocking the keyring*
At this point your keyring is still locked. If you need that unlocked, you'll have to use xdotool to unlock your session. Wait a couple seconds so the keyring gets unlocked. Then lock the desktop again.*

### Option 2: Temporarily enable automatic login remotely; then disable.

Making this happen is not hard. It's just a bit of a hack. Essentially, all you have to do is edit a gdm3 config file (`/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`) to enable the auto login feature on your account. Then you restart the gdm3 service, and disable the auto login feature. This will leave your system logged into your account. Finally, don't forget to lock the screen remotely so that a password is needed for physical access. ... Though we all know that your login password does little to protect your system from someone who actually knows what he/she is doing.

If you are not comfortable doing this manually, you can use a script I put together that will do it for you (available at [my GitHub](https://github.com/nbros652/remote-gdm3-login)).

---

### *EDIT: Unlocking the keyring*

My original answer did not address unlocking the keyring which may be needed for some applications. I have modified my script to make this happen as well, but it requires the installation of xdotool (to automate filling in your password on the lock screen). My script will prompt to install this if it's not already installed. The xdotool requires a running X session, so all I had to do was modify the script to log in using a password after the screen had locked and then lock it once more. The xdotool cannot be used on the initial login screen.
Now here's the kicker, the desktop session must remain unlocked long enough for the keyring to get unlocked. You can check to see if the keyring was unlocked by running `seahorse` with X forwarding over SSH. If the login keyring has a locked icon, you need to go into my script and set the `unlockKeyringWait` value to a higher number and try again.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this soon! What do you mean by the login password offering little protection? Are you referring to booting from a pendrive or about physically taking the disks? I'm asking to see if there's a security issue I'm not aware of.

Comment: Ok, so this is actually super cool, but I just realized that there's only one problem with it: the passwordless login doesn't unlock the keyring, hence no software relying on passwords can start normally. I see some solutions here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/18927/how-to-enter-the-default-keyring-password-via-the-command-line, but if I unlock the keyring AFTER using your script the programs will have already not started. Would it be possible to unlock the keyring before?

Comment: As for protection, yes, I'm basically referring to someone booting from a live USB/DVD or simply physically accessing the drive. In either case, unless you use FDE, an attacker could modify the gdm3 config file and bypass your password entirely. Unlocking the keyring before login is a cart before the horse problem. I am going to edit my script to unlock the keyring right after login, but you'll have to test it to see if the keyring unlocks before your other apps try to access it. Look for an edit to my answer in a little bit.

Comment: I don't know if my edits will unlock the keyring before your startup applications try to access it. In the event that the keyring is not unlocked in time, you might consider dumping your applications into a single script that will delay their start. Your script might look something like this (sorry comments don't allow new lines). `#!/bin/bash (new line) sleep 60; [start applications]`. Then remove your apps from the startup programs and include this script instead.

Comment: I haven't been able to check it yet, but I gave you the bounty anyway :)

Comment: Let me know how it goes once you've had a chance to try it.